# Unit (real unit test) of test laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

## Background

- Framework: laravel 9.x
- PHP 8.0
- Continuous integration (Travis CI etc)

I am working on a project that is legally very sensitive, so testing is vital.

Due to project requirements, the project requires 100% unit testing and code coverage. This is a project requirement, even if it is relatively pointless in a few % of the cases. Just to be clear: the relationships work as expected in the functional/feature testing, however... this is for Unit testing. Traditional, no dependencies (mocks etc) unit tests.

To be clear: this is an exercise in reaching 100% coverage NOT necessarily "good" testing.
Adding a "testing ignore" line needs to be justified, so this "suboptimal test" is still the best option for the project.

## Question

How is it possible to UNIT test the following function:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

// declaration: normal laravel model 
class Product extends Model
```

```php
    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

This needs to be a Unit test.
This testing will be run without a database connection, preferably without any other classes (except for mocks).

Comment: Model tests are ideally done with a database but you can always use an in-memory sqlite database if you don't want to connect to a separate DBMS server (the configuration is commented out [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/phpunit.xml#L24)) however the issue with this approach is when using DB specific things that might not work in sqlite. In those cases or more complex tests you could use mocking but for this simple test case just use sqlite

Answer (score 3):

You would unit test a relationship the same you would anything else. No mocks needed...

1. Setup your data;
2. Executing your function; and
3. Assert your results.

```
/** @test */
public function a_product_can_access_its_associated_user()
{
    //Setup
    $product = Product::factory()
                ->for(User::factory()->create())
                ->create();
    
    //Executing & Asserting
    $this->assertTrue($product->user()->exists());
}
```

For more information on creating models with relationships in Laravel, [review their documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#belongs-to-relationships).

Comment: Create method will persist data to db no?